# ¿Por qué pasa la variable de tipo estructura por referencia en la función para cargar los clientes?

Tags: c++, funciones, estructuras, paso-por-referencia

```
  struct Cliente{
    char nombre[30];
    char clave[10];
    int edad;
};

struct Nodo{
    Cliente c;
    Nodo *siguiente;    
};

//Prototipos de Funciones
void cargar_cliente(Cliente &);
void insertarCola(Nodo *&,Nodo *&,Cliente);
bool cola_vacia(Nodo *);
void suprimirCola(Nodo *&,Nodo *&,Cliente &);
```

void cargar_cliente(Cliente &); sería la parte que se me está complicando entender, no en sí, sino el por qué del paso por referencia en lugar de simplemente pasar la variable.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Bienvenido. Sin saber el código de la función es difícil darte una respuesta acertada.

Answer (score 0):

De forma simple, lo que está ocurriendo y por qué ocurre esto en el código es que su función `cargar_cliente()` solo recibe una referencia a esa variable del tipo `Cliente`. De esta forma, lo que recibe es la dirección de la variable y no la variable en sí.

De esta forma permite hacer cambios en la variable original de esa función, incluso si la función se llama en otra función.

El operador `&` se utiliza para crear una referencia a la variable, la variable valor será accedida directamente, sin tener que copiarla a la función.

```
void printValor(int &valor)
```

Así se pasa por valor, lo que ocurre es una copia del valor de la variable "valor" que se pasará a la función.

```
void printValor(int valor)
```

Usando esta forma, lo que sucederá es que se creará una copia local de la variable y los cambios se aplicarán solo a esa copia local.